# Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'

Tags: fonts, warnings, font-encodings

I know this issue has been solved for the phv font family and updated via CTAN/miktex console but I get the same error for eurosans.sty. (pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21, MiKTeX 2.9.7400 64-bit)

```
Package: eurosans 2004/01/26 v3.1 using the Adobe Euro fonts (WaS)


LaTeX Warning: Font shape declaration has incorrect series value `mc'.
               It should not contain an `m'! Please correct it.
               Found on input line 47.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: that is a warning not an error, and it is noisy but harmless. You could write the author about it. Btw: in my miktex the sty is no longer installed.